# FB.UI params doesn't affect to dialog window

Tags: javascript, facebook, fb.ui

I want to add *Facebook share button* to my site. I created app on Facebook. Ran local server. Added to host-file *127.0.0.1 dev.mysite.com* and added domain *mysite.com* and website *http:/ /mysite.com*(without space) to app settings in Facebook. Trying:

```html
function shareOnFacebook(){
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        display: 'popup',
        title: 'myTitle',
        href: 'mysite.com',
        caption: 'mysite.com',
        picture: 'http://www.picturesource.com/path/picture.jpg',
        description: 'myDescription'
    }, function(response) {
         if(response && response.post_id){}
         else{}
    });   
}
```

but in dialog window infromation is filled without params, that i sent with function *FB.UI*. Did i miss something necessary for having permission to put information to the dialog window?

Comment: If i just put **https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=184484190795&caption=mysite.com&description=myDsecription.&display=popup&href=mysite.com&picture=http://www.picturesource.com/path/picture.jpg** to address bar then dialog window will be right. But if i will change app_id to mine(**184484190795** fbrell's id), there will result like i've just put only link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the API v2.9, this is no longer possible to customise the content of the feed dialog : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#deprecated-params

The only part you can customise is the "quote" content, which look like that :

[image: Quote param with the API v2.9]

Your code doesn't work because even if you force the API v2.5 or v2.8 with the "FB.init" call, each new Facebook APP is using the v2.9 :

[image: you can't downgrade a Facebook APP]

If you don't have any old Facebook APP in your own repository (< v2.9), you can't use the good old feed dialog.

Comment: Thank you! It was realy helpful. I was read this article on my native(russian) language and the latest information was dated by July 17, 2015.

Comment: Is there any other JS possibility to share a specific Image, Name and Description ?REgarding to the Documentation it should still work https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog there are just a few deprecated params ...

Comment: Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog?locale=en_US#v2_9_90_day_deprecations
It looks like it is really dead ... -.-

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog) for that, not the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog). The Share Dialog basically only accepts the URL to share and gets the OG Data from that URL.

Comment: On my local server doesnt work to. So i tried to run on http://www.fbrell.com and both methods work fine.

Comment: urls need to be public to share them

Comment: Yes, they are public. **href: 'mysite.com'** is realy existing website.